# Force equal current between 2 pins

Tags: current-limiting, power-connector

Is there a way to force current to be shared equally between 2 pins?

I need to supply 10A (at either 24 or 48V DC) through a connector.

The simple way would be to use a 10A per pin rated connector. But those fitting my needs are both bigger than I would like, and quite expensive.

There are smaller and much cheaper connectors (that we already use elsewhere in our design) that are rated 5A per pin, but have enough pins to use 2 pins per direction (ie 2 for GND and 2 for Vcc=24V or 48V). There are not enough pins for 3 pins per direction. So provided current is perfectly shared, I could use this connector to pass 2*5A=10A.

The problem is that current is not perfectly shared (a slight difference in contact resistance is enough to unbalance currents), or even worse, the user might connect to only one pin, and all the current will go through that single pin.

Is there a way (adding some components on the supply PCB) to either:

- force equal current sharing
- limit current to 5A on each channel, in such way that when one channel is "full", the other takes the rest of the share

The price difference between the 2 sets of connectors is >100$, so price is not much of a constraint.

I already have e-fuses I use elsewhere to prevent global over-current on a connector, which I can easily add as well to this connector. But they go open in case of overcurrent, so they can't be used to do the current sharing (but are usable to prevent over-current if the current is equally shared).

Comment: You need to specify the voltage compliance if you're enforcing sharing. Do you tolerate a 1 V, or 2 V, or 100 mV difference between the pins before shutting off the current hog? 100 mV might be enough for contact resistance differences. This affects how much power the sharing circuit has to dissipate if it's linear. I suspect you don't want to go to the expense and complexity of switch-mode for higher voltage tolerance. I suspect e-fuses might have enough residual resistance to make different contact resistances share reasonably well.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the voltage compliance? The maximum voltage drop allowed in the balancing system? let's say 500mV max, but less would be nice (500mV is already 5W). Or the maximum voltage drop difference between both wires ? (I haven't measured it, but I suspect <0.1 ohms, excepted if on cable is not connected). NB : the efuse might help to balance the high side, but not bot ground side

Comment: You could measure the currents in all 4 pins and introduce some PWM for pins that exceed 5 A. This would keep the temperature rise of the pin in the connector in safe limits. You can fully disconnect if the balance fails.

Comment: Use a transformer to let the two currents be equal. But this will "consume" some voltage ... To be verified.

Comment: @Antonio51 Could you please elaborate on how a transformer might help (for DC current)?

Comment: It is a "well-known" problem for forcing currents to be equally shared between two SCR paralleled but I don't know if it is usefull with DC.

Comment: Have a look at XT30 and/or XT60 connectors, primarily used for connecting batteries in model cars/aircraft.  They are not expensive ($1-2 per pair in qty 10, far below the $100 you are trying to avoid) and reasonably small compared to what you're asking.  I used them recently to upgrade from a barrel jack and they worked well.

Comment: @BenVoigt : the connectors I'm speaking about are sub-sea connectors, and those don't come cheap (and choice is quite limited, at least as long as you want to remain in the "cheaper" range (<1k$ per connector))

Comment: @Sandro: Fair enough.  Just want to also point out that running at 100% of rating is generally not recommended either.  Normal design process includes derating for age, temperature swings, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt : good point. I suppose the derating is already done by the constructor (they claim <0.01 ohms contact resistance, and 20AWG wires, so there should be some margin, but I will double check with the manufacturer if I go this route)

Comment: Considering that 10A @ 24V is 240W, then would not using 48V let you drop the total current to 5A if you add a DC-DC on the other side of the connector?

Comment: The problem is that the other side is often some of the shelf equipment (or supplied by the client). And adding a converter in between would mean adding a watertight enclosure and connectors for entering an leaving the enclosure. So maybe 2000$ to house a 20$ DC/DC converter. But the main reason for providing the 48V is that it carries twice the power at given current (most equipment is 24V), so bigger equipment might be connected.

Comment: I think what people do **in reality** is they take 2 pins at 5A each, just connect them in parallel and hope for the best, which usually does turn out okay. But sometimes not, as in Nvidia's 12V_HPWR connector.

Answer (score 4):

A little ballast resistance in each path will help share current equally between them. First look at the current imbalance without ballast:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx1UdJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the fuses represent the connectors, and R3 and R4 are cable/connector resistance, slightly mismatched.

Now insert some small but deliberate additional "ballast" resistance in each line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwidRK.png)</sup>

That's brought the currents much closer together, at a cost of about 0.2V total lost across the resistors. They will be dissipating about 1W, so make them beefy.

Active solutions will be complex, and probably won't have any benefit over the above. Still, if you don't mind getting your hands dirty, here are a couple to ponder.

This next circuit doesn't share current equally, but it does clamp current through one path (via the 130mΩ resistor) to a maximum of 5A. When that threshold is reached, Q1 begins conducting, sending all additional current via that route instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frb5Mh.png)</sup>

This circuit will lose 0.7V, and dissipate over 3W in R1 and Q1, so be sure to heat-sink transistor Q1, and use a beefy resistor.

This is how currents are distributed as I ramp load current from 0A to 10A. Blue is current through ammeter AM2, and orange is AM1:

[image]

If that 0.7V drop is too much, then you'll need to use a smaller current sense resistor, the voltage across which will require amplification. In this next design, R1 and Q1 dissipate only a little over 1W, and the voltage lost across those elements is only 0.2V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBGInR.png)</sup>

Comment: Solution 1 is quite elegant, I will just have to quantify the worst case "normal" unbalance (and rely on e-fuses for mis-connection resulting in no sharing at all). Solution 3 is also quite interesting (specially as it allows connecting a single pin if current is low enough). I will have to think about how to make the symetric (I have the problem on the ground pins as well as on the 24V pins)

Answer (score 2):

Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

Here is a circuit that "could" do what is needed.
This works with "balanced" inputs.
Do the same "work" for the negative pins of the board.

It works in transient "low frequency". L1 and R3 :  +/- 10 %.

[image]

Something as this, from [Coilcraft: Common Mode Line Chokes – CMT](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/76bae3db-61c6-46b3-a704-e0609219dd4f/cmt.pdf)

[image: excerpt from Coilcraft datasheet]

Comment: I will have to think a bit about it to really understand how the transformer maintains the balance. Or is it just the resistors themselfs? (nb : your simulation was done with nearly identical resistors : what if one connection has slightly higher resistance?)

Comment: It is the transformer (10 mH -> 100 mH) that makes the balance. 100 mOhm is the ESR of each inductor. As they are wired "together", they are very equal to some %. And the transformer is not too "great" (some \$cm^3\$).

Comment: Thanks. Then I will just have to simulate how it behaves when adding also (different) resistors for the wires, to create some inbalance (if everything is perfectly balanced, then the currents are naturally balanced)

Answer (score 1):

> I could use this connector to pass 2*5A=10A

Yeah, at room ambient air temperature, in other words: it's a fantasy.

With a 5A/pin connector, you'll need *at least* 4 pins to share the 10A load. More pins if your product is supposed to work above 45C ambient, or in direct sunlight, or is running hot inside, etc.

Running any contacts at their maximum ratings is very iffy business, as it assumes that everything else is perfect: no air pollution that causes contact degradation, contacts not worn nor abused, room temperature air around the connector, etc. Read the datasheet carefully to understand what this "5A max per pin" rating **actually** means!

> The problem is that current is not perfectly shared

If you measure things carefully, you'll notice that the pin that carries most current will warm up quickly, increase its resistance, and decrease its share of the current carried. It is a self-stabilizing system, but you absolutely can't be anywhere near the per-pin rated current.

If you asked me what would keep me sleeping well at night, then carrying 1.5A per pin would be reasonable, and 1A per pin (in a 5A/pin connector) would be downright relaxing. This far away from rated current the current sharing works quite well. For single-pin use, 2A/pin would be just fine, but when the currents are distributed, less is better.

Again, forget about running the pins at their maximum rating. The thing will melt in no time flat once you put it for testing in the environmental chamber.

You will test it in the environmental chamber, won't you?

If you don't have the money for decent environmental testing, you have to pay for the pins. You can't have the cake and eat it too. It's one or the other. Do expensive testing and component qualification, or comfortably overdesign.

More pins in a connector doesn't cost a fortune - certainly way cheaper than alternatives, like field failures, potentially a fire hazard, etc.